# Putty and screen under CentOS 6

Tags: putty, gnu-screen

My current work enviroment is Windows workstation with Putty. And almost always i run "screen" session.
When i started using CentOS 6 i noticed strange behavior with screen. When I run screen in Putty ssh session the size of window (terminal) is reseted (rows and cols were  changed).
For me this is very anoying and i'm unable to resolve this. Maybe someone know what to change in Putty config or terminal settings (termcap/termininfo or screenrc) to stop this behavior?
I hope someone understand me. English is not my best side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a](https://superuser.com/questions/113944/how-to-prevent-screen-from-resizing-my-terminal-in-mac-os-x) [bunch](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7316906) [of](https://superuser.com/questions/217066/prevent-gnu-screen-from-resizing-display-size) [links](http://aperiodic.net/screen/appearance#screen_resizing_despite_-a_when_using_putty_on_windows_iterm2_on_mac_os_x) from a quick [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=gnu%20screen%20resize%20terminal), one of these solutions should work:

- A: Add this line to your `~/.screenrc` or `/etc/screenrc`:

  ```
  termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
  ```
- B: Always run screen with the `-A` option
- C: Dig arround PuTTY's settings until you find an option to disable remote screen resizing (unlikely)

Comment: FYI, Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) already has the described `termcapinfo` command in its `/etc/screenrc` file.  RHEL/CentOS does not, because it is commented out (`termcap` and `terminfo` commands on line 65; `termcapinfo` is equivalent to both).